# Удобный плагин для верстальщика

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, chrome-extension, плагин

В каком-то видео на ютубе видел плагин для браузера, который загружает изображение макета и ставит его поверх страницы, которую вы верстаете. Можете напомнить название плагина/официальную ссылку на скачивание

Comment: трушные верстальщики через background прописывают

Comment: Просто, думаю, через плагин быстрее))

Comment: Быстрее чем написать одну строчку?

Comment: PerfectPixel  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfectpixel-by-welldonec/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi?hl=ru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для Firefox => https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/perfectpixel/?src=search

Для Chrome => https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfectpixel-by-welldonec/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi